# How to include both audios when overlay video on video with FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay

I have 2 inputs: `video.mp4` (with audio) and `notif.mov` (with audio). I want to overlay `notif.mov` on `video.mp4`. I tried this code:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4  -i "notif.mov" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0" output.mp4
```

Both videos playing simultaneously, but sound missing from second input (`notif.mov`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i notif.mov -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay;[0:a][1:a]amix" output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i back.mp4 -i petite.mp4 -filter_complex "overlay=20:20" output.mp4

ffmpeg -y -i out.mp4 -i 1080_Happy_Holidays_Red_Videvo.mov -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=iw/4:-1[pip];[1][pip]overlay=100:100[watermark];[watermark][2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" output.mp4
```

Comment: This will not include the audio from `notif.mov` as mentioned in the question.